# Moodle crashes my server during the installation

Tags: php, apache, moodle

I have Moodle 2.3.3+ and after I press "continue" in  "extension check page" in the installation the server will stop and when i try to access any domain on the server this message will come up:

`The connection was reset`

and after 3-5 minutes the server will response again and the installation will continue to the "admin registration" and when i press "submit" the server will crash again without saving the admin information.

Server Specifications:

- Dedicated Server
- Intel® Core™ i7-920 Quadcore
- RAM 24 GB DDR3 RAM
- Apache/2.2.16 (Debian)
- PHP/5.3.3-7

PHP Log:

```
PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: CFG in /var/www/clients/client1/web4/web/index.php on line 32 
PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/clients/client1/web4/web/index.php on line 32
PHP Warning:  require_once(/course/lib.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/clients/client1/web4/web/index.php on line 32
PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required '/course/lib.php'(include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /var/www/clients/client1/web4/web/index.php on line 32
```

any ideas why is that happening?

Comment: Try to fix the errors and the file that is missing and see if it still crushes

Comment: Do you have all the requisites for Moodle? http://docs.moodle.org/20/en/Installing_Moodle#Requirements

Comment: @ElzoValugi the file is not missing i checked it .. and the moodle works fine sometimes.
and my server have all the requisites for moodle

Comment: you still get that error in the logs?

Comment: yes i still get it each time

Comment: then you have to fix that first. even if the file exists, probably is not on the path the moodle expects it. check /var/www/clients/client1/web4/web/index.php on line 32 and see if /course/lib.php is an absolute of relative path, maybe you have to add something to the php include_path. Moodle or you should not have absolute pats like this one /course/lib, I suspect this should be relative to something, like a internal root that is not correctly defined.

Comment: I think, that something wrong with Moodle config. `$CGF` is undefined and after that Moodle try to include `course/lib.php` with default relative path (`/`)